# Data by reference instead of value

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that has a menu and it has an option to set the "current" date. I can define the date and it will stay until the program shuts down. I've got another method to get the date, by asking the user the date when linking a person to it, the problem is that it wont go on the main data on the main menu. It will only be the data for the .date on the person structure, I guess I explained it well. I've tried many ways and I really can't figure it out, if someone can help me out...

```
typeData readData() {    
    int val;
    typeData data;
    do {
        printf("Day: ");
        data.day = readInteger(MIN_DAYS, MAX_DAYS);
        printf("Month: ");
        data.month = readInteger(MIN_MONTH, MAX_MONTH);
        printf("Year: ");
        data.year = readInteger(MIN_YEAR, MAX_YEAR);
        val = validateData(data);
        if(val == 0) {
            printf("The data is not valid.\n");
        }
    } while (val == 0);
    return data;
}
```

I think I need to get it by reference but I'm trying for some time already and can't do it. Thanks everyone.

Comment: The code you posted is OK. Your problem must be elsewhere. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you trying to save the return value somewhere like typeData i ;i=readData() ?I am aasking this because I feel your program is correct .It must set the value in date

Answer (score 5):

While it's legal C, passing structs *by value* and returning them is usually not the best way.  Consider:

```
void
readData(typeData *data)
{

    int val;

    do {
        printf("Day: ");
        data->day = readInteger(MIN_DAYS, MAX_DAYS);

        printf("Month: ");
        data->month = readInteger(MIN_MONTH, MAX_MONTH);

        printf("Year: ");
        data->year = readInteger(MIN_YEAR, MAX_YEAR);

        val = validateData(data);
        if (val == 0) {
            printf("The data is not valid.\n");
        }
    } while (val == 0);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is a sample main program plus sample changes to `validateData`:

```
int
validateData(typeData *data)
{
    int data_valid = 1;

    // check for error
    // this is whatever checks you already do ...
    if (data->... != ...)
        data_valid = 0;

    return data_valid;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    typeData main_data;

    readData(&main_data);

    // do something useful with the data [or transform it, etc]
    processData(&main_data);

    // print some results
    printData(&main_data);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

Here's a modified [partial] program, based on your latest example.  I had to guess at the overall organization, but, at least it has the necessary changes to `menuPrincipal`:

```
int
validateData(typeData *data)
{
    int data_valid = 1;

    // check for error
    // this is whatever checks you already do ...
    if (data->... != ...)
        data_valid = 0;

    return data_valid;
}

char
menuPrincipal(typeDate *date)
{
    char option;

    if (date->day == 0 && date->month == 0 && data->year == 0) {
        printf("Date not set yet.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Date: %d/%d/%d", date->day, date->month, date->year);
    }

    // more stuff

    return option;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    typeData main_data;
    char option;

    while (1) {
        readData(&main_data);

        option = menuPrincipal(&main_data);

        switch (option) {
        case 'a':  // do something
            break;

        case 'b':  // do something else
            break;

        default:
            printf("unknown option: '%c'\n",option);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #3:**

Based on your latest comment, I think I see what you're having trouble with.  I've taken your latest code snippet and updated:

```
// your original code -- this no longer works because readData is now void
if (data->ano == 0 && data->mes == 0 && data->dia == 0) {
    Blah[*Bleh].date = readData(*data);
}

// one possibility -- but it does _not_ update "data"
if (data->ano == 0 && data->mes == 0 && data->dia == 0) {
    readData(&Blah[*Bleh].date);
}

// this is more likely what you want -- it updates _both_:
if (data->ano == 0 && data->mes == 0 && data->dia == 0) {
    readData(data);
    Blah[*Bleh].date = *data;
}
```

Comment: It worked as you said, it's just not working now on the validateDate place, it says that it's an incompatible argument with (validateData)

`void readDate(typeDate *date)
{
    int val;
    do
    {
        printf("Day: ");
        date->day = readInteger(MIN_DAYS, MAX_DAYS);
        printf("Month: ");
        date->month = readInteger(MIN_MONTH, MAX_MONTH);
        printf("Year: ");
        date->year = readInteger(MIN_YEAR, MAX_YEAR);
        val = validateDate(*date);`

Comment: Look at my original update.  It has a sample change for the `validateDate` definition [I had to guess at that].  You probably still have `int validateDate(typeDate data)` instead of `int validateDate(typeDate *data)`. Change it and then call it with `val = validateDate(date)`.  Within `validateDate`, change any `data.` into `data->` in your real version.  The general rule is:  with `sometype *ptr` use `ptr->xxx` [what we're doing now].  The old way was: `sometype val` and using `val.xxx`

Comment: Here's a page to look at: http://denniskubes.com/2012/08/20/is-c-pass-by-value-or-reference/ In particular, what we've been doing here is part of the "Passing Structs to Functions" section. The 1st example is "pass-by-value", [what your code was doing originally]. The swap doesn't work correctly [similar to the problems you were having]. The 2nd example is "pass-by-reference" [what we've been doing]. The swap now works. What we're doing now is just converting the last of your "pass-by-value" code into "pass-by-reference" consistently across all functions

Answer (score 0):

It works now, I was using

```
val = validateDate(&date)
```

on the original function for `readData`, now I changed it to

```
val = validateDate(date)
```

and it works!

I just don't know why I need to use `date` instead of `&date`, I thought that if I was passing the parameters by reference I needed a '&' symbol.